# delete database entry in ListActivity android

Tags: android, database

may i ask for help...i manage to add data to database..but i got problem to delete the data..because i can't delete based on ID from my ListView...how to get the ID??..this is my code..

This class name as ViewActivity.java where i display my database content...i only display one column only in my ListView

```
   String query = "select * from " + helper.TABLE_PEKERJA;

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(c!=null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int getNamaIndex = c.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_NAMA);

            if(c.isFirst())
            {
                do{
                    String nama = c.getString(getNamaIndex);
                    result.add(nama);
                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

in my DBHelper, i create a method for delete row from my database table which is here..

```
public void deleteData(SQLiteDatabase db, String id)
{
    db.delete(TABLE_PEKERJA, COL_ID + " = " +id, null);
}
```

then still in the class ViewActivity.java, i implement method onListItemClick

```
    @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();        

    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String keyword = o.toString();
    helper.deleteData(database, keyword);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data " + keyword + " removed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

also got this error..this error only i can view...this error at part

```
Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);

02-09 02:34:23.729: E/Database(28923):  at com.example.untukmuna.ViewContentActivity.onListItemClick(ViewContentActivity.java:69)
```

So, my question is

1) How do i delete my database table row, when i press item in ListView based from ID
2) when creating database, there has db.open()...but where should i close database buy putting db.close() ...??

thanksss~~ hope you all understand my question.. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way that it is conventionally done is that you simply get the `id` from the list click parameter.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) <------
```

But you can't immediately do this because your `ListView` is hooked up to an `ArrayAdapter` and not a `CursorAdapter`. Right now, that `id` will either always be 0 or some non-sense value. I would recommend that you change your adapters if you need to do tasks like this.

But if you need your adapters as is, then what you could do is make a corresponding `id` collection of some sort that you fill as you loop through your database to fill `result`. Then it would be as simple as getting the `position` from the `onListItemClick` parameter then getting the `id` from the id collection.

you'd of course, have to make sure that you're deleting the value off this collection as you're deleting the row of the listview.

---

try the following:

```
private DBHelper helper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Long> idList = new ArrayList<Long>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    helper = new DBHelper(this);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();      

    String query = "select * from " + helper.TABLE_PEKERJA;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int getIdIndex = c.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_ID);
    int getNamaIndex = c.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_NAMA);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        idList.add(c.getLong(getIdIndex));
        result.add(c.getString(getNamaIndex));
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

public boolean deleteData(Long id) {
    return db.delete(TABLE_PEKERJA, COL_ID + " = " + id, null) > 0;
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Long idValue = idList.get(position);
    boolean isDeleted = deleteData(idValue);
    Toast.makeText(this, "boolean value for database deletion: " + String.valueOf(isDeleted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    idList.remove(position);
    result.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //refresh so that we can see listview changes
}
```

Comment: thanks for you code...i use you code, but i'm not copy all..just take part onListItemClick..but when i run, it shows error..which says indexoutofbound...i'll edit and copy the result for you at my answer bellow..

Comment: you're getting the error because you're trying to get something from a collection that hasn't been filled yet. `idList.add(c.getLong(getIdIndex));` is critical. that can't be omitted.